# Why is an error not shown in the console?

Tags: flutter

I have a FutureBuilder

```
FutureBuilder<bool>(
  future: getFuture(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data) {
        //Data is true and should show something
      }
      //Data is false and should show something
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
);

Future<bool> getFuture() async {
  var myList = [];
  //Intentionally makes an error
  if (myList.first == 'foo') {
    //This should no be fired
  }
  return true;
}
```

When i run this setup in Flutter the CircularProgressIndicator spins happily while nothing else happens. There's no error showing in the console, so if I had not planted the error itentionally i would not know why the code was not working. If the `getFuture()` method was very complicated it would take ages to find the error without it showing in the console.

Does anyone know why the error does not show in the console? Is there a way to get the error to show?

**EDIT**

Thanks to some comments i now know i should add the following to the start of the FutureBuilder

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
  print(snapshot.error); //Output: Bad state: No element
  //Handle error
}
```

Now the console outputs

```
Bad state: No element
```

Opposed to before i now get some infomation through the console but the error output is not that helpfull. It does no tell me where the error occurs, which makes it much harder to debug. Say I have a very complex `getFuture()` method it would take me ages to find where the error occurs.

Am I out of luck and will this be the best output the console can give me? Or is there a way for me to make the error output of the console more detailed?

Comment: Is `if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('${snapshot.error}');` not what you're looking for?

Comment: *"Does anyone know why the error does not show in the console?"* - it is because they do not `print`  the `error` reported here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2783f8e2e1/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart#L771 - they simply return `AsyncSnapshot<T>.withError`

Comment: @WillHlas apparently that was exactly what I was looing for. But often answers lead to new questions. See edit for my new question